# how to tell a user exactly why login failed in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I have a membership provider and i have several reasons a login can fail that I need to relay to the user.

Everything I have read involves a lot of code.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

You can put your out-of-band data into the context when in your provider and then pick it up in the error handler of your login control to set the failure text.

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
   // in membership provider
   HttpContext.Current.Items["loginFailureReason"] = "Locked Out";
   return false;
}

// in login codebehind
protected void Login1_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Login1.FailureText = (string) HttpContext.Current.Items["loginFailureReason"];
 }
```